# Why isn't the isa pointer hardwired in Objective-C classes?

Tags: objective-c, gcc, clang

I've been studying the Objective-C runtime for some years, and even hacked libobjc a little bit (both Apple's and GNUStep's), and I've been wondering about a design decision on the compilers.

Every Objective-C object is expected to have its size at least of `sizeof(Class)`, having its first field being `Class isa`, as seem in `struct objc_object`. We see it's explictly declared in root classes like `NSObject` and old defunct `Object`. We also know that the runtime adds the pointer to the new objects when they are created by `class_createInstance()` (see code example below).

So, my question is: then why isn't the `isa` pointer automatically prepended to the class declarations? Why does it need them to declare it explictly even if that is error-prone?

Example with bad code:

```
#import <stdlib.h>
#import <stdio.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface Foo {
  @public
  int x;
};
- (void)bar;
@end

@implementation Foo
- (void)bar {
  printf("bar\n");
};
@end

int main() {

  Class cls = objc_getClass("Foo");
  printf("cls = %p\n", cls);

  // Returns sizeof(int)
  printf("cls size = %ld\n", class_getInstanceSize(cls));

  Foo *obj = class_createInstance(cls, 0);
  printf("obj = %p\n", obj);

  // Are we saving isa?
  printf("hmm: %d\n", *((Class *)obj) == cls);

  // We are! This works ;)
  [obj bar];

  // Evil code
  obj->x = 10;

  // Did we do something wrong?
  printf("hmm: %d\n", *((Class *)obj) == cls);

  // Yeah, we did! Segfault here!
  [obj aaa];

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
};
```

Comment: Careful. Things change. Whatever you think about details of an instance implementation might not be true.

Comment: Well, when I first started playing with it, five years ago, the above behavior was already true, and caused a segfault. I tested it again yesterday to write this question, and same thing happened. I can't see any reasonable reasons `isa` is not implicit in root classes... so I'd like to know if there is any. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's an implementation detail of the Apple/GNUstep/OpenStep Objective-C runtime. `libobjc` is the Apple Objective-C runtime, and Cocoa/GNUstep classes like `NSObject` are tied to that Objective-C runtime.

Objective-C (originally) just adds a minimal layer of syntax on top of C, and there's no reason, from a pure Objective-C language point of view, that objects need to be laid out any particular way.

You could theoretically write your own Objective-C runtime that lay out objects and do other stuff differently, and then you write your own Objective-C framework, with your own root classes to work with that runtime.

Comment: I understand that, but... this doesn't seem a good reason. Clang has a separate code emitter for each Objective-C runtime (for Apple's libobjc4, for GNUStep's libobjc2...), so it knows which runtime you are using and it knows that the `isa` field is required. It could add it for you on root classes, or, at least, warn you when the first field is not a `Class`, to avoid broken code.